# the filldraw in tikz change it positon alone

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, draw, tikz-graphdrawing, fill

I am trying to  generate my own title page for my beamer, I  treid the follwong:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\fill[blue!20!black] (-7,1) rectangle (7,6);
 \fill[blue!25] (-7,1) rectangle (7,-0.5);
\fill[white,opacity=.3] (-7,-0.5) rectangle (7,-4);
\node[ ] at (-6,2) {{\textcolor{white}{\Huge{  }}}};
\node[ ] at (-6,0.5) { };
\node[ ] at (-6,-1.5) { };    
%\node[] at (4.2,4.9) {\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{ }};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the fiildraw are not covering the whole slide, they are a bit shifted to the left, whatever I change their coordinates, whereas  I want them to cover the whole slide. Even more, when I change the titles in the nodes (above I keep them empty) the filldraw shifts more to the left.

Can someon help me solve thi sproblem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use an overlay picture, e.g. `\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
\fill[blue!20!black] (current page.north west) rectangle 
 ([yshift=-5.5cm]current page.north east);
\fill[blue!25]([yshift=-5.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle 
 ([yshift=-7cm]current page.north east);
\fill[white,opacity=.3] ([yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle 
 ([yshift=-5cm]current page.north east);
\node[anchor=north west,font=\Huge,text=white] at ([yshift=-3cm,xshift=1cm]current page.north west)
  {Blub};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}`

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you very much for your comment, Ithink if you post it as an  answer it will be great. One more thing, I am new to  tikz,  so I am not sure what would "anchor" and "xshift, yshift"  do, can you propose a guide for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to fill a page or do something relative to page coordinate, you may want to use the `current page` node. To access its anchors (like `north`, `west`, `south east` and so on), you need to dial the `overlay,remember picture` keys. Then you can draw objects using these page anchors. For instance,

```
\fill[blue!20!black](current page.north west)
        rectangle ([yshift=-5.5cm]current page.north east);
```

fills a rectangle defined by two corners: the upper left corner of the page/frame and the point 5.5cm below the upper right corner of the page/frame. That is, `yshift=<distance>` means "shift the y coordinate by `distance`". `xshift` works analogously.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \fill[blue!20!black](current page.north west)
        rectangle ([yshift=-5.5cm]current page.north east);
 \fill[blue!25]([yshift=-5.5cm]current page.north west)
        rectangle ([yshift=-7cm]current page.north east);
 \fill[white,opacity=.3] ([yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west)
    rectangle ([yshift=-5cm]current page.north east);
 \node[anchor=north west,font=\Huge,text=white] at
  ([yshift=-3cm,xshift=1cm]current page.north west)
  {Blub};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish to remove the navigation symbols on the lower right, you may use `\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty`. And `graphicx` does already get loaded by `beamer` and `tikz`, you do not need to load it separately. samcarter is at topanswers.xyz kindly informed me that beamer loads `amsfonts` and `amssymb`, and that with an up-to-date `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is also unnecessary.

Comment: @ user194703  how do I write `on` the Madrid theme using overlay, remember picture